# How to manage user authentication for hyperledger using msp and fabric-ca-client?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am developing an application over fabric 1.3 . I have built a network on multi-node setup, connected peers, instantiate chaincode and have my network up and ready for invocation and queries.

Now, I am thinking to make a log-in portal through which a user can register/enroll and perform invoke/queries. All my peers and orderer are on cloud, and am planning to provide this log-in feature using the Node SDK exposed on a cloud instance.

I went through the official doc:
https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#registering-a-new-identity

I can see that we need fabric-ca component to register users and enroll them for queries. Upon enrollment, we get a cert files under ~/.hfc-key-store.

Now I want to understand how should I go ahead with my flow.

User signs up on network:

```
fabric_ca_client.register({enrollmentID: 'user1', affiliation: 'org1.department1'}, admin_user)
```

User log in with his secret:

```
 fabric_ca_client.enroll({enrollmentID: 'user1', enrollmentSecret: secret});
}).then((enrollment) => {
  console.log('Successfully enrolled member user "user1" ');
  return fabric_client.createUser(
     {username: 'user1',
     mspid: 'Org1MSP',
     cryptoContent: { privateKeyPEM: enrollment.key.toBytes(), signedCertPEM: enrollment.certificate }
     });
}).then((user) => {
     member_user = user;
     return fabric_client.setUserContext(member_user);
```

Invoke/Query as user1:

```
var store_path = path.join(os.homedir(), '.hfc-key-store');
Fabric_Client.newDefaultKeyValueStore({ path: store_path
        }).then((state_store) => {
            // assign the store to the fabric client
            fabric_client.setStateStore(state_store);
            var crypto_suite = Fabric_Client.newCryptoSuite();
            // use the same location for the state store (where the users' certificate are kept)
            // and the crypto store (where the users' keys are kept)
            var crypto_store = Fabric_Client.newCryptoKeyStore({path: store_path});
            crypto_suite.setCryptoKeyStore(crypto_store);
            fabric_client.setCryptoSuite(crypto_suite);
            // get the enrolled user from persistence, this user will sign all requests
            return fabric_client.getUserContext('user1', true);
        }).then((user_from_store) => {
            if (user_from_store && user_from_store.isEnrolled()) {
                console.log('Successfully loaded user1 from persistence');
                member_user = user_from_store;
            } else {
                throw new Error('Failed to get user1.... run registerUser.js');
            }..
```

Now, what shall I do when a user logs out? delete the ~/.hfc-key-store certs? Since these certs are going to be stored on server side where Node script is running, so it doesn't make sense.

Also, is my flow correct or if there is any better way to accomplice my objective?

Comment: In addition to the answer below - 1. Suggest to use the new programming model, not Fabric 1.3 - see concepts, architecture, app development approach here (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/developapps/developing_applications.html) and the Fabcar sample (registration + interaction examples) https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/fabcar/javascript

Comment: 2. your app users blockchain identities shouldn't be deleted after logout of the application - the user will use his cert/key combo, from his/her designated wallet (see docs) again, when next he/she interacts (from the app) with the blockchain network.

Comment: Hi @Piyush, Where are you storing your all user certs? As an application running on the server. How we can manage 300+ user certificates?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar login implementation that I had to do, As you said I did create certificates for each registered user as well as stored the basic user information in MongoDB.

The flow that I went with is that once the user is registered the user certification is created as well as his login credentials such as username and password are stored in MongoDB.

When the user tries to login back, I would check the MongoDB as well as the certification to see if the user has already registered, once logged in the user would then be in possession of an auth token which he then can use to interact with the fabric-client.

Comment: Hey, thanks for response. I wanted to check the ACL permission on blockchain level too, therefore I wanted to implement blockchain level signup and login.

Answer (score 0):

When an identity (certs and keys) is issued by CA then it should be persisted for that particular user for future interactions (either by saving in client wallet or other methods) so if you delete it then there will be re-enroll process on each log in and it will slow it down too.

To resolve it -
 1. Create separate logic like JWT token for log in and session management.
 2. Save the keys and certs on server directory (not the best way but will work for now later)
 Let me know if it satisfies your query.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I had implemented an okta layer for front-end and JAVA back-end. I wanted to make sure user is authenticated on blockchain level as well, so that I can ensure he is able to perform a specific chaincode call with respect to his role assigned.

Comment: Okay, you can check with fabric-ca about the specific role for that user identity. Fabric-ca handles the access for specific roles at the configuration level in configtx.yaml for like identities like peer,user,admin etc so you can check the config file for it, but checking it using fabric-SDK as you want is not available right now/. let me know if anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late but maybe it can help someone. My approach is to do what you do in the login, in a register method where I return the certificate and the private key, then on login the user needs to provide both the certificate and the private keys generated (and also the certificate and the private key for the TLS connection), and with this information I recreate de Identity and store it in a MemoryWallet, and with this MemoryWallet now, I can create the gateway and connect to the blockchain.

It would be something like this

```
const identity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity(mspId, certificate, privateKey);
const identityTLS = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity(mspId, certificateTLS, privateKeyTLS);

const wallet = new InMemoryWallet();
await wallet.import(userId, identity);
await wallet.import(userId + '-tls', identityTLS);

const gateway = new Gateway();
await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: userId, discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: false } });
const client = gateway.getClient();
const userTlsCert = await wallet.export(userId + '-tls') as any;
client.setTlsClientCertAndKey(userTlsCert.certificate, userTlsCert.privateKey);
```

Hope it helps